# How to prove the sum of two given subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $W_1=\{A \in M_{n×n} (F): A_{ij}=0$ when $i<=j\}$ and let W_2 be the set of the simetric matrices $n×n$. Both $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $M_{n×n} (F)$.
Prove that $M_{n×n}(F)=W_1 \oplus W_2$

I'm totally a novice in linear algebra, so this problem seems overwhelming to me. I don't understand what does $A_{ij}=0$ mean. I know the definition of $\oplus$ but I'm confused, this seems to abstract to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W_1$ is the subspace of matrices that have $0$s in the diagonal and above. It is a subspace because multiplying those matrices by a number (scalar) and summing them gives you a matrix of the same type. You can check this; the same goes for symmetric matrices ($W_2$).

To prove $M_{n×n}(F)=W_1 \oplus W_2$ you could prove that any matrix can be expressed as a sum of two matrices, one of each type, and the intersection $W_1\cap W_2$ is the zero vector.

Given some matrix $B$, it's clear that $B_{ij}$ for $i\le j$ can't be given by $W_1$, since that part is always $0$ in $W_1$, so you need a symmetric matrix $C$ from $W_2$ such that $C_{ij}=B_{ij}$ for all $i\le j$. Then $C$ is determined, since it has to be symmetric. To generate the $B_{ij}$ for $i>j$ take just $D=B-C$. It's easy to check $D$ is in $W_1$.

Now take a matrix $E$ in the intersection of $W_1$ and $W_2$. Since $E$ is $W_1$ it has zeros in the diagonal and above, and since it is in $W_2$ it is symmetric and thus it has to be the zero matrix. Can you see why?

This is the general idea for the solution; you'd have to write it down in a formal way. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand it better now. But what do you mean by saying that "$W_1$ has 0s in the diagonal and above". What diagonal? And where is above? And why did you take $B_{ij}$ for $i>j$ and then $D=B-C$?

Comment: The positions $i\le j$ in a matrix are the diagonal ($i=j$), and the entries above the diagonal ($i<j$). For example, in a 2x2 matrix those positions are (1,1), (2,2) and (1,2).

Comment: On the other hand, $B_{ij}$ are the entries of $B$, and you want to generate $B$ as a sum of two matrices, so you need to get those entries in some way. For $i\le j$ you use a symmetric matrix, since it is the one allowed non zero entries there. For $i>j$ you need to get rid of the entries of $C$ first (we have entries there for $C$ because it is symmetric, so $C_{ij}=C_{ji}$), and then add the entries of $B$ we're interested in.

Comment: This is done imposing $D=B-C$. Note that if we impose this we are simply saying $B=C+D$, which is what we want. The important thing there is that $B-C$ is actually a matrix in $W_1$, which is true since $B_{ij}=C_{ij}$ for $i\le j$ by construction, and thus $D_{ij}=B_{ij}-C_{ij}=0$ for $i\le j$.